How to find electro-thermal analysis of an arbitrary shape of conductor?
I have an arbitrary shape of conductor in a step file. I would first like to find the resistance of said conductor and then observe the change in resistance due to change in temperature. I do not have an idea how to approach this. Is there a free software where I can do this simulation? Help would be really appreciated.
